# Require an java application example for GPB message with oneof field type

Tags: protocol-buffers

Protocol Buffer has field type "oneof".

I have read the documentation and have defined message.
But not sure how to use it in application. Can someone provide me an example to use in in Java.

-Set one message of oneofRequest fields

-Know which message I have set

-Fetch the info set in step 1

```
    message TypeA
    {
        oneof OneOfRequest 
        {
            TypeX getX;
            TypeY getY;
            TypeZ getZ;
        }
    }

   message TypeX 
   {
       uint32 pos;
   }
   message TypeY
   {
        uint32 type;
   }
   message TypeZ
   {
       string name;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been posted for a while. Since I was having the same sort of question and no one answered, I would post my answer here just in case if some one is needing.

My answer is simply use `builder`, which is generated by `wire`, a tool I think is really helpful to play with `protobuf` in java/android. For more info, see https://github.com/square/wire .

Once you have wire included in your project and your proto class get generated correctly, you should be able to use it easily. Since all the class generated would have a inner class `builder`,

you can initialize your it by: `$yourclass.Builder().build`

and you can decode it using `Wire` class